# How does the Ranged Disarm feat work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, ranged-attack, disarming

D&D 3.5, Complete Warrior, Ranged Disarm feat.

It only says that we can attempt a disarm attempt with a ranged weapon, but not much else.

So, two questions:

1. Does the enemy still have an attack of opportunity, even if he has a melee weapon and I'm 25 feet away?
2. If I miss, does he still have a chance to disarm me?

My guess would be that the answers are "no" for both questions, but it seems a bit powerful (disarm with no AoO, and no consequences if it missed).

Answer (score 5):

### 1 - Maybe, but if he can, he would already do it anyway. Most of times, not.

It's a disarm attempt made from distance. Apart from the distance, all normal rules of Disarm still applies since you can't benefit from the feat Improved Disarm. However, you're 25ft away; unless your enemy can reach and threat this distance (i.e. Huge creature with a reach weapon) he can't make an AoO against you and if he can, he would already do because you're shooting while in his threatened area.

### 2 - Unlikely.

Unless the rare condition of an enemy with outstanding reach being the target of your attempt, there's no reason to even think about something like that. If the condition is true though, I think it's ridiculous but RAW he will be able to try to disarm you since you still can't benefit from the Improved Disarm feat.

> My guess would be that the answers are "no" for both questions, but it seems a bit powerful (disarm with no AoO, and no consequences if it missed).

You paid a feat for it, you know? Improved Disarm also let you try to disarm someone without being retaliated and it is even more reliable.

**PS:** Either way, I really don't recommend trying to disarm two-handed reach weapons from huge or bigger enemies with your ranged weapon because they will have a lot of bonuses in their favour anyway and can reach you under 30ft.

Comment: This answer is good (+1 already), but could be improved by expanding the balance concern raised at the end of the question. In particular, the AoO on combat maneuvers effectively means that, without the relevant Improved feat, they are simply unusable. No one should ever take an AoO with a maneuver—because if they’re provoking, they shouldn’t be using the maneuver. Which raises a number of systemic concerns—the fact that the rules are written in such a way that suggests you could do something, when in fact that this is a mistake, and the “do you have the feat for that?” problem.